# Generating monthly invoices for a group of users given a parameter 

Tags: c#, .net

I'm planning an app that will be used to manage invoices and payments for the members of a club. In this early stage I already hit a roadblock: how am I going to generate invoices for each member's monthly payment according to a user defined parameter? That is, the administrator will be able to group users and select an invoicing date then each month at that date an invoice will be generated for each user in that group.

I really don't know where to start here, currently I'm searching for a .net version of a cron job ... although from what I've seen, such an alternative is not very doable on shared hosting account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to schedule and execute various tasks.

Comment: Can this run in a shred environment tho? I can't find a definiative answer yes/no on the site ... looks interesting tho +1

Comment: @WestDiscGolf, what do you mean by *shred environment*?

Comment: @Darin I'll guess he meant _shared_ environment :-)

Comment: @driis, I guess so, but the question then will be: what is *shared environment* :-)

Comment: A shared environment would be something like an account in winhost where you basically get a virtual directory without many config/rights management options.

Comment: btw thanks for the link Darin, will be checking it out in a few

Comment: @JoseMarmolejos, `without many config/rights management options` is not very precise description of an environment.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did mean "shared" environment. I mean as in shared hosting where you don't get rdp to the server, or control to install services etc. on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting environment doesn't give you access to have scheduled tasks, you could fake it by setting up a web page or web service which when called by the right user starts the process, then create a tiny client app that calls it and schedule *that* on a client machine somewhere.

Really, the only other option without scheduled tasks is going to be to write code so that whenever something hits the website, it checks to see if it's done it's processing for today (and if not, goes and does it). The problem is really meant to be solved by scheduling.